# My .Net socket handler is missing packets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I’m writing some code in .Net/C# to communicate with some factory equipment over Ethernet.   I first assign a handler:

```
  _TCPConn.BeginReceive(
      _StateObject.sBuffer, 0, _StateObject.sBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
      new AsyncCallback(Socket_DataArrival), _StateObject);
```

And then in my handler, first thing,  I do an *EndReceive*, then I transfer the data from the socket’s buffer to my own input buffer for further processing later, I log some stuff, then I do a *BeginReceive* to start things up again and I exit the handler.  So ...

```
....
   StateObject stateObject = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;        
   int bytesReceived = stateObject.sSocket.EndReceive(ar);

// transfer bytes, log stuff,  then reenable receive and leave . . . 

   _TCPConn.BeginReceive(   _StateObject.sBuffer, 0,
   _StateObject.sBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
   new AsyncCallback(Socket_DataArrival), _StateObject);

   return;
```

This works fine most of the time but if the factory equipment sends 2 packets close together it fails.   Here's a Wireshark (network sniffer) output.  The first column is the time delta from the previous packet in microseconds (yes, "micro", not "milli")

```
002397  10.1.1.116  10.1.2.11  TCP  ....  Len=6
000024  10.1.1.116  10.1.2.11  TCP  ....  Len=9
```

When this happens the first packet seems to disappear - the handler never gets called for the 6 byte packet, only the 9 byte one.   I know the packet's arriving on the PC because Wireshark shows it.

BUT if we introduce a delay in the factory equipment, so instead of 24 microsec's it's 10 millisec's the problem goes away.   Unfortunately that's not a solution because there's a large base of installed equipment in factories around the world we can't change.

Any suggestions for how to debug and fix this?   **Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Can you post the code that reads from the socket?

Comment: Can you confirm that if the two packets arrive at the same time you are not receiving 15 bytes total (9+6). Two individual sends using sockets can be received in a single handler callback.

Comment: It would be crucial to understand how you parse the received data. Sometimes the sockets can internally buffer the received data, so you would receive only 1 callback where the buffer contains both payloads (6+9)

Comment: @Daniel  Some of it is proprietary but I could probably disguise it.  The bigger problem is that it would make the original post a lot longer.   If there's a demand for it then I could add it as an edit - I'm trying to keep the original post concise and not too hard to read.

Comment: @MarkF  - bytesReceived is 9 and the contents exactly match what Wireshark reports.

Comment: @m0sa  see my response to MarkF -  also the contents of the StateObject's  sBuffer exactly match the 9 byte packet -  no sign of the other packet's data in the buffer.

Comment: @user316117 - Are you 100% the handler is not running twice. It's difficult to see what else might be going on. Try adding some Console.WriteLine() in various places to see what is going on if you have not already.

Comment: If you concatenate 3 bytes from the second packet to the 6 from the first one - is that sequence of bytes different form the sequence sent in the second packet?

Comment: @Markf - yes 100%  - for debugging I made an external array of Strings to record the bytecount and first few bytes of each packet when the handler is called and it's never being called for the missing one.

Comment: @Maciej - yes totally different - the protocol this equipment uses is that first packed is basically a duplicate of the last packet the PC sent (we use it for confirmation it was received properly) and the second packet is the actual response from the equipment to the PC.

Comment: Ok, obviously I have no idea what the explanation of the observed behavior is, but I have decided to share some thoughts on what voodoo rituals you could perform next in case you didn't come up with them already :). 1 check what the change in the setting of the delay (from 24 microseconds to 10 milliseconds) changes in the packets, but not in the payload, but in the data for the lower layers of the TCP/IP stack. 2 try another method of receiving data (just for test) - dedicated thread with blocking socket. 3 try receiving data (again just for test) in plain Win32 API.

Comment: There is a conceptual problem here. The TCP model of communication is a continuous stream of bytes, not a sequence of "packets". It is IP that cuts the stream into packets, and the "packets" your application serializes into the stream are not necessarily correlated with what you will see with Wireshark. Can you inspect with Wireshark the whole contents of the TCP communication, including ACK packets?

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing EndReceive(ar) you should keep receiving.  Process the received packets separately. you need not stop receiving.